# Calculate flex-basis based on amount of react children

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

i'm trying to do a calculation of `flex-basis` based on the amount of children.

```js
  div {
    /** TODO: Calculate number of children / 100 */
    flex-basis: ${props => 100 / React.Children.count(props.children)} %;
  }
```

Now this doesn't work, any hints on what i'm missing here??

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: This is solvable with pure css, you don't need to do any calculations in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution.

```js
import React from 'react';

const YourComponent = ({children}) => {
  const style = {
    div: {
      display: "flex",
      width: "100%",
      flexBasis: `${100/React.Children.count(children)}%`,
      justifyContent: "space-around"
    }
  }
  return <div style = {style.div}>{children}</div>
}

export default YourComponent;
```

[CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-hodgkin-8g106?file=/src/YourComponent.jsx)

Comment: This has exactly the same effect as if you do: `display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-around"` There is no advantage to adding the flex-basis calculation. Use pure CSS!

Answer (score 0):

Worked like this:

```js
  div {
    flex-basis: ${props => {
      const amountOfChildren = React.Children.count(props.children)

      return 100 / amountOfChildren
    }}%;
  }
```

Comment: Did you even try pure css?

Comment: This component i'm building has to be able to contain varying amounts of children.

Comment: Which is possible with CSS, you shouldn't ever have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do here, can't you just set flex-basis to 100%?

```css
.flex {
  display: flex
}
.child {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
.child:after {
  content: 'child';
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This example gives you the same result as your accepted answer above with pure css, I don't understand why you need to calculate flex-basis with js, that's not how css is supposed to work.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>Hello</div>
  <div>Hi</div>
  <div>Bonjour</div>
</div>
```